# What is 'a in F#

Tags: f#

While learning `F#` and reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/classes) page, I found this code:

```
type MyGenericClass<'a> (x: 'a) =
   do printfn "%A" x
```

I did not understand the meaning of `'a` is it related any how to `lifetime` concept at `rust` or something completely different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'a` is a type parameter, such as `T` in `List<T>`.  The F# syntax for type parameters is to preface the name of the parameter with the tick mark.  In your example, this means that the parameter `x` can be any type, and it will create a `MyGenericClass` of that generic type.  For example, if you called `new MyGenericClass(3)`, you would get a `MyGenericClass<int>`.